# Parse Push Notifications: Another Error Occurred

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, push

I'm getting a weird issue since last night testing with Parse. I was able to send push notifications just fine but now none of my push notifications are being delivered when I send them via the parse push notification tool online.

**Edited** Ok so it seems this is only an issue for local environment. When I test push notifications going to my test app installed via test flight it seems ok. I checked and I have both the prod and the dev apple certificates in my account...

The delivery report is not very helpful either. Here is the message it gives me

[image]

Any idea what is going on? Is anyone else experiencing this? Below is my payload

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok this was a certificate issue. Seems like Apple revoked my certificate for some reason (no clue why since it had over 11 months left on it).

I went through and created a new development certificate and the rest as covered in this article and boom it works!

https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

Hans