# WinRT Parse Push Notifications: Another Error Occurred

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, push

Having this weird error not sure what is going wrong. Details are same from [Parse Push Notifications: Another Error Occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34534860/366096) question, **In this case it is using WinRT platform. Might not be certificate issue as on Parse dashboard it only requires Package SID & client secret for windows store.** It seemed to be working sometime back. Any help appreciated.